# How to convert int [] to Big Integer?

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I would like to convert an integer array of values, which was original were bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you know in which format your `int[]` is meant to be interpreted.

Each int can be seen as consisting of four bytes, and these bytes together can be converted to an BigInteger. The details are the byte order - which byte is the most and which one the least significant?

Also, do you have a signed or unsigned number?

A simple way to convert your `int`s to `byte`s (for latter use in a BigInteger constructor) would be to use `ByteBuffer` and wrap an IntBuffer around it.

```
public BigInteger toBigInteger(int[] data) {
    byte[] array = new byte[data.length * 4];
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
    IntBuffer ibuf = bbuf.asIntBuffer();
    ibuf.put(data);
    return new BigInteger(array);
}
```

Obvious adaptions would be to set the byte order of `bbuf`, or use another BigInteger constructor (for unsigned).

Answer (score 2):

Well, what about [new BigInteger(byte[] val)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5b%5d%29)?

To quote the API docs I linked to:

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.